# Passing a list of values using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out the best way to pass a list of values to a function using vb.net. Basically I need to pass a string, Object, String which could be a list of 10 or less.

an example would be:

```
String, Object, String
String, Object, String
String, Object, String
String, Object, String
String, Object, String
```

I am trying to find the best way to pass this type of data structure. I have used arrays in the past but not sure this would be the best solution for this type of thing plus if there is a better way I'd really like to learn something new.

Thanks.

Comment: those represent *something* so write a class to contain them, then put the lot of them in a `List(of T)`  where T is the class you write to contain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a custom class or structure that holds these values:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public MyString1 as String
    Public MyObject as Object
    Public MyString2 As String

End Class
```

Then you can create/populate your list with a collection of these objects and pass that collection to the method.

```
Dim myList as New List(Of MyClass)
' Populate the list here with myList.Add statements
```

Then create your method signature as such:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal list As List(Of MyClass))
```